# SQL merge column with same ID but different value

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains IDs paired with names:

```
ID | Name  
3    Cole
4    Mart
4    Dino
7    Pitta
7    Leo
7    Mina
8    Bob
```

There is a user that has the same id. The output I'm looking for is:

```
ID | Name  
3    Cole
4    Mart
null Dino
7    Pitta
null Leo
null Mina
8    Bob
```

Entries that have the same ID will be displayed once, and any remaining entries that share the same ID will list null.

Is there a way to write a query that will perform this, using SQL?

Comment: What is logic to keep/ change ID to `null`? Which record's id will be `null`, which record's id will be kept? For e.g, why you kept `Mart` not `Dino`? You want the max of name or just keep random record? And what is your RDBMS?

Comment: Do you just want output (a `SELECT` statement) or do you want to update records? (`UPDATE` statement). You need to explain why you picked Dino, not Mart. Remember there is no 'order' in a table - you need to have an order by key.

Comment: what I want is to keep the data of dino, leo, mina. but there ID will be display as null because as you can see. the ID is already in there. 4 and 7.

Comment: You want to hard code Dino, Leo, Mina in your logic? I don't think so. You need to explain the logic of why for example you picked Dino over Mart. But the order of the data cannot form part of this logic unless there is an actual column that you ordered by.

Comment: For example: pick the alphabetically last name to preserve and make the others null. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Fix it in the presentation layer instead.

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So there is no such thing as the *first* row among several with identical values.

You can set *one* of the rows to `NULL`, but cannot determine which.  For this, use `row_number()`:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by id order by ?) = 1
             then id
        end) as id, name
from t
order by id, ?;
```

`?` is for the column that specifies the ordering, so the "first" in the group will have a value and the rest `NULL`.